# Card arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

Seven identical red and three identical black cards are laid in a row on a table. How many different arrangements are possible if no two black cards are allowed to be adjacent to each other?

> What is the most elegant approach to this problem? The total number of ways to arrange these cards is $10\choose3$. From this we can subtract $8\choose7$ to remove the cases where all $3$ black cards are next to each other. What is the best way to remove the cases just 2 are next to each other and is there a more elegant approach than subtracting the compliment from the total? Thanks

Comment: Hint : The 7 red cards form 8 islands.  At most 1 black card to an island.

Comment: @user2661923 are you suggesting stars and bars?

Comment: Yes, Stars and Bars will work here, but it isn't really needed.  You can intuit the answer immediately, from my hint, without doing any math.

Comment: I see, if we say an island is the gap between red cards there exist 8 islands. We pick 3 of these islands to be occupied and we get $8\choose3$ ways where no black cards are adjacent. however there was some math done here is this what you were suggesting? @user2661923

Comment: Yes, my idea is that conjuring $~\binom{8}{3}~$ from my hint doesn't require Stars and Bars.

Comment: That's clever, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that subtracting the complement from the total would be too cumbersome,also difficult to scale up for harder values.Instead , lay down the 7 identical red cards first, then among the 8 gaps, between the red cards you can choose 3 .gaps to place the black cards.
So ,total possible arrangements:$$\binom{8}{3}=56$$